# Total Sum With Vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two spreadsheets with names and times. One is specific session times and on the second sheet, I want to sum up the total times based on each instance from sheet one.

```
Sheet 1: Session Time
Name   |   Time 
David        5
Mike         2
Daniel       3
David        2
Daniel       8


Sheet 2: Total Time (The one for which I need a forumula)

Name   |  Total Time
David        7
Mike         2
Daniel       11
```

I tried a countif and vlookup but I couldn't get it match more than one instance of the name on sheet 1. I also tried this suggested formual from a suggested post but its not summing a second instance of the user name

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(ifna(VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheet 1'!A3:AA16, 5, false))))
```

A2 = David (On Sheet 2)

Sheet 1'!A3:AA16 = List of names in columns A and all the way to AA is a series of columns with numerical values

5 = the column number from with I want to return the sum for every instance of David (2 in this example with a total of 7)

False = its not sorted

Any help is mucho appriciado!

Comment: See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25798/sum-values-with-same-name

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula in your `Sheet2!B1`:

```
={"Total Time";arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",sumif(Sheet1!A1:A,A2:A,Sheet1!B1:B),""))}
```

Or simply use `=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",sumif(Sheet1!A1:A,A2:A,Sheet1!B1:B),""))` in `Sheet2!B2`

- Get the sum of the range based on a specific criteria using [SUMIF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)
- Basically, get the sum of `Sheet1!B1:B` if `Sheet1!A1:A` matches the current cell being checked in arrayformula `A2:A`

### Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you have encountered some issues. I just based the sample sheet data from your sample provided. I didn't get why you used `Sheet 1'!A3:AA16` from your previous formula. You might want to share a sample sheet if you can't make the proposed solution work from your side. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: Actually, all I needed was a simple "sumif" I just wasn't familiar with this command and was trying to layer logical expressions into a regular if statement. Thank you all for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a simple QUERY, e.g.,

`=QUERY('Session Time'!A:B, "Select A, SUM(B) WHERE A Is Not Null GROUP BY A LABEL SUM(B) 'Total Time'")`